# How can use SQL query to get values from DB in arrays for a line chart

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch data from DB for a line graph using the below code.

```
    <?php
        $dataPoints = array( 

            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM chart_data_column WHERE value = 'now'";
            $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
            if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {                               
            while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) { 

         array("y" => 25, "label" => "Sunday"), ?>

             } } else { } 
      );
    ?>
<script>
 window.onload = function () {

   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
  text: ""
      },
  axisY: {
  title: ""
      },
   data: [{
type: "line",
   dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
   }]
   });
  chart.render();
 }
</script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
         <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Using the above code it gives as error as **Un-expected Syntax error, expecting ) instead of ; at $dataPoints line**

However if i m to remove the sql query, graph plots with static data perfectly.

Any Help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the entire query inside the array.  You need to separate them.  Also, you have "chart_data_column" where the table name should be.

```
$dataPoints = array();

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM chart_data_column WHERE value = 'now'";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataPoints[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here how do i assign fetched values to x and y.. like `array("y" => 25, "label" => "Sunday"), ?>` sunday & 25 in the given static data.?

Comment: $row[0] will give you the first returned column value, $row[1] the second etc...

Comment: here i have 2 column values, that i need to fetch

Answer (score 1):

I have to commend you for keeping PHP code and JavaScript separate. This is a very good idea. However, if you want to fetch all records from MySQL using PHP and mysqli library you do not need to have any loop. You can just fetch everything into an array and then display with `json_encode()` in JavaScript.

```
<?php

// import your mysqli connection before

$result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM chart_data_column WHERE value = 'now'");
$dataPoints = $result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>
<script>
 window.onload = function () {

   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
  text: ""
      },
  axisY: {
  title: ""
      },
   data: [{
type: "line",
   dataPoints: <?= json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
   }]
   });
  chart.render();
 }
</script>
```

`<?=` is short for `<?php echo`